# Connect R to Smartsheet via API?

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, httr, smartsheet-api

I am looking to connect to "scrape" a SmartSheet file that was shared with me and retrieve the results from a table. From there I want to convert the table to a data frame.

How would I connect to Smartsheets API? Is it using HTTP or REST? How would I convert the retrived data into a data frame?

Comment: A quick google for [`cran smartsheet`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cran+smartsheet) suggests https://github.com/elias-jhsph/rsmartsheet might be a reasonable start. Even if you cannot use the package for whatever reason, perhaps its methodology will give you a step in the right direction. This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on StackOverflow.

Comment: yeah I was looking at this but the documentation is very sparse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a small but extensible API client R library for smartsheet: https://github.com/cole-johanson/smartsheetr.

For the above request, make sure to follow the README, then use:

```
library(smartsheetr)
library(dplyr)

sheet_name_of_interest = '<sheet name>'
your_sheets = ss_get_sheets()
sheet_id_of_interest = your_sheets |> filter(name == sheet_name_of_interest) |> pull(id)
ss_read_sheet(sheet_id_of_interest)
```

Comment: You have just saved me so much time, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this to get a data frame from a Smartsheet. You just need to pass it the sheet ID (can get from the sheet File-Properties dialog) and your api key. This function retrieves a csv version and then loads it.

```
getsheet <- function(sheetid, apikey) {
  authstring <- stringr::str_glue("Bearer {apikey}")
  urlstring <- stringr::str_glue('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetid}')
  
  h <- curl::new_handle()
  curl::handle_setheaders(h,
                    "Authorization" = authstring,
                    "Accept" = "text/csv")
  
  tmp <- tempfile()
  curl::curl_download(urlstring, destfile = tmp, handle = h)
  rawdata <- readr::read_csv(tmp, show_col_types = FALSE)
}
```